# nagios grouping notifications

Tags: nagios

Is it possible to configure nagios to group notifications into a single e-mail?  Sometimes when something goes down my inbox gets spammed with all the notifications.  It would just be nice if these could somehow be lumped together.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know of a method to group the mails, but when you add dependencies to your hosts and services you will not get too much mails.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to your question is "yes", but it would take a lot of work. A better response would be to fix the problem of your getting so many emails.

Here's my question: Are you getting a bunch of emails because a bunch of things go down, or because one thing goes down, and everything else alerts because that one thing is broken?

If you give us more information about the situation, I'm pretty sure we can come up with a better way to arrange your configuration so that you only get the notifications you need to take care of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do, using something along the lines of [Noma, the Nagios Notification Manager](http://www.netways.de/de/produkte/nagios_addons/noma/). I'm not sure Noma will do exactly what you need, but the idea of delegating the actual notifications to a second system is probably what you're looking for.

It's quite a lot of work, and, probably you'll be better off doing

1) Setting up hosts's "parents" correctly

2) Setting up hosts and services dependencies correctly